# How long did Vamana take for his second step? Any Scriptural references

Tags: vishnu, puranas, vamana

So, how long did Vishnu in Vamana avatar take for his first and second step to scale the universe and Earth? For him to grow big and encompass visible universe, the space and heavens...and finally Earth. How long exactly did that take? 
Any Scriptural references appreciated.

Comment: I think that took as long as the first step. No more and no less. As the scaling could be done by stopping and starting time as appropriate for the scene..:-)